# Oracle - making table with amount gradually decrease

Tags: oracle, reduce

I have table tbA

| ID(auto) | KEY | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID1 | 50 |
| 2 | ID2 | 10 |

(one)

tbB

| ID(auto) | KEY | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID1 | 8 |
| 2 | ID1 | 5 |
| 3 | ID1 | 2 |
| 4 | ID2 | 5 |
| 5 | ID2 | 3 |

(many)

I expected have table `tbMatching` (mapping via KEY)

tbMatching

| IDM(auto) | IDA | IDB | AmountBefore | Amountdecrease | AmountAfter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 50 | 8 | 42 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 42 | 5 | 37 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 37 | 2 | 35 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 2 |

Please help, how to make that?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Please post your current code and describe what is the issue with it. You need to look for running sum

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUM` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT a.id AS ida,
       b.id AS idb,
       a.amount - SUM(b.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY b.key ORDER BY b.id) + b.amount
         AS amountbefore,
       b.amount,
       a.amount - SUM(b.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY b.key ORDER BY b.id)
         AS amountafter
FROM   tbb b
       INNER JOIN tba a
       ON a.key = b.key
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tba (id, key, amount) AS
SELECT 1, 'ID1', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ID2', 10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tbb (id, key, amount) AS
SELECT 1, 'ID1', 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ID1', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'ID1', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ID2', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'ID2', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| IDA | IDB | AMOUNTBEFORE | AMOUNT | AMOUNTAFTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50 | 8 | 42 |
| 1 | 2 | 42 | 5 | 37 |
| 1 | 3 | 37 | 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 4 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Aw9f0n-M)